# Get Memory (Private Working Set) of Process

Tags: c#, powershell

My problem is what i am getting for WorkingSet is very different than Task manager Memory (Private Working Set). I have tried various solutions written on NET but the values are far too away from matching. Kindly help me get Memory (Private Working Set) from task manager.

```
script += string.Format(@"$Processes = Get-Process -ComputerName {0} | Sort-Object WorkingSet -desc | Select-Object;", remoteMachineName);
script += @"$ProcessArray= @();";
script += @"foreach ($process in $Processes) {";
script += @"$ProcessName = $process.ProcessName;";
script += @"$ProcessSize = $process.WorkingSet/1KB;";
script += @"$objAverage = New-Object System.Object;";
script += @"$objAverage | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name Name -value $ProcessName;";
script += @"$objAverage | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name Memory -value $ProcessSize;";
script += @"$ProcessArray +=$objAverage; }; ";
```

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/802785/powershell-get-process-and-task-manager-discrepancy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is shown in Process Manager as **Memory (Private Working Set)** is the value of the performance counter `\Process\working Set - Private`.

You can retrieve this value with:

```
$ProcessPrivateSet = Get-Counter "\Process(instancename)\Working Set - Private"
$WSPrivateKiloBytes = $ProcessPrivateSet.CounterSamples[0].CookedValue / 1KB
```

`$WSPrivateKiloBytes` is now the same value as what you see in Process Manager.

---

The problem with retrieving this value for a distinct process is that performance counters name process instances by process name + instance count, rather than by process ID.

So, if you launch 1 instance of a Java application, you may retrieve the counter for the `java.exe` process, like so:

```
Get-Counter "\Process(java)\Working Set - Private"
```

Now, if you launch another one, you'll need to reference that one like this:

```
Get-Counter "\Process(java#1)\Working Set - Private"
```

and so on and on.

You can change this behavior by setting the `ProcessNameFormat` for performance counter objects on the local system like this:

```
$RegPath = "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\PerfProc\Performance\"
Set-ItemProperty $RegPath -Name ProcessNameFormat -Value 2 -Type DWord
```

A value of 2 means "include process ID in instance names", a value of 1 (default) would mean "use an instance counter" (like shown above).

The new format will be `processname_id`

---

After changing the `ProcessNameFormat`, you can now retrieve performance counters for a specific Process ID, like so:

```
$javap = Get-Process -Name java | Select -First 1
Get-Counter "\Process(java_$($javap.Id))\"
```

Since you now have a distinct correlation between `Get-Process` output and the performance counters, you can now retrieve the "Private Working Set" value for each process, with a single `Select-Object` statement using a calculated property:

```
Get-Process java | Select Name,Id,@{Name="WSPrivate(KB)";Expression = {(Get-Counter "\Process($($_.Name)_$($_.Id))\Working Set - Private").CounterSamples[0].CookedValue / 1KB}}
```

It *will* take some time to retrieve each individual counter sample, so if you plan on doing this often or for a large set of processes, you might want to use a wildcard (`*`) and retrieve `\Process(*)\Working Set - Private` and then look at the `InstanceName` in each entry in `CounterSamples`